# Filter custom post types by a field value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have custom post type of an animal type. (I.E I created an animals collection).
I want to give the user a drop down to select the gender and filter the displayed custom post types entries accordingly.
Right now the gender is a custom field but I can change that if there is a better approach.
I already managed to display my collection by creating an archive-animal.php.
How can I do that? I know to code but new to WordPress.

Comment: Well, show us the code you've tried.

Comment: I'd suggest using a taxonomy instead of a custom field. Querying by a custom field tends to perform poorly.

Comment: Assume I use taxonomy, What are the main guidelines about drop down controls for filtering? Is there any built-in mechanism to display them and filter by them or should I tailor it on my own?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this article:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/ .
I know that it causes a page refresh but going for Ajax based solution is an overkill. 
This solution code is very elegant and easy to follow and understand.
Although taxonomy might be faster they require a lot of work with creating metaboxes and stuff so for small custom post type (Very few entries) there won't be a performance penalty.